# SQL counting distinct over partition

Tags: sql-server, count, window-functions

I have a table with two columns, I want to count the distinct values on Col_B over (conditioned by) Col_A.

**MyTable**

```
Col_A | Col_B 
A     | 1
A     | 1
A     | 2
A     | 2
A     | 2
A     | 3
b     | 4
b     | 4
b     | 5
```

**Expected Result**

```
Col_A   | Col_B | Result
A       | 1     | 3
A       | 1     | 3
A       | 2     | 3
A       | 2     | 3
A       | 2     | 3
A       | 3     | 3
b       | 4     | 2
b       | 4     | 2
b       | 5     | 2
```

I tried the following code

```
select *, 
count (distinct col_B) over (partition by col_A) as 'Result'
from MyTable
```

count (distinct col_B) is not working.
How can I rewrite the count function to count distinct values?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is how I'd do it:

```
SELECT      *
FROM        #MyTable AS mt
CROSS APPLY (   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT mt2.Col_B) AS dc
                FROM   #MyTable AS mt2
                WHERE  mt2.Col_A = mt.Col_A
                -- GROUP BY mt2.Col_A 
            ) AS ca;
```

The `GROUP BY` clause is redundant given the data provided in the question, but may give you a better execution plan. See the follow-up Q & A [CROSS APPLY produces outer join](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/239865).

Consider voting for [OVER clause enhancement request - DISTINCT clause for aggregate functions](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32890510-over-clause-enhancement-request-distinct-clause) on the feedback site if you would like that feature added to SQL Server.

Answer (score 7):

You can emulate it by using `dense_rank`, and then pick the maximum rank for each partition:

```
select col_a, col_b, max(rnk) over (partition by col_a)
from (
    select col_a, col_b
        , dense_rank() over (partition by col_A order by col_b) as rnk 
    from #mytable
) as t
```

You would need to exclude any nulls from `col_b` to get the same results as `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

Answer (score 7):

This is, in a way, an extension to [Lennart's solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/239810/6965), but it is so ugly that I dare not suggest it as an edit. The goal here is to get the results without a derived table. There may never be the need for that, and combined with the ugliness of the query the whole endeavour may seem like a wasted effort. I still wanted to do this as an exercise, though, and would now like to share my result:

```
SELECT
  Col_A,
  Col_B,
  DistinctCount = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Col_A ORDER BY Col_B ASC )
                + DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Col_A ORDER BY Col_B DESC)
                - 1
                - CASE COUNT(Col_B) OVER (PARTITION BY Col_A)
                  WHEN COUNT(  *  ) OVER (PARTITION BY Col_A)
                  THEN 0
                  ELSE 1
                  END
FROM
  dbo.MyTable
;
```

The core part of the calculation is this (and I would first of all like to note that the idea is not mine, I learned about this trick elsewhere):

```
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Col_A ORDER BY Col_B ASC )
+ DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Col_A ORDER BY Col_B DESC)
- 1
```

This expression can be used without any change if the values in `Col_B` are guaranteed to never have nulls. If the column can have nulls, however, you need to account for that, and that is exactly what the `CASE` expression is there for. It compares the number of rows per partition with the number of *`Col_B` values* per partition. If the numbers differ, it means that some rows have a null in `Col_B` and, therefore, the initial calculation (`DENSE_RANK() ... + DENSE_RANK() - 1`) needs to be reduced by 1.

Note that because the `- 1` is part of the core formula, I chose to leave it like that. However, it can actually be incorporated into the `CASE` expression, in the futile attempt to make the entire solution look less ugly:

```
SELECT
  Col_A,
  Col_B,
  DistinctCount = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Col_A ORDER BY Col_B ASC )
                + DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Col_A ORDER BY Col_B DESC)
                - CASE COUNT(Col_B) OVER (PARTITION BY Col_A)
                  WHEN COUNT(  *  ) OVER (PARTITION BY Col_A)
                  THEN 1
                  ELSE 2
                  END
FROM
  dbo.MyTable
;
```

[This live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bf726f090c954e302e666bc76563ceac&hide=3) at [image: dbfiddle logo]db<>fiddle.uk can be used to test both variations of the solution.

Comment: This is a great solution, I wonder why isn't this not applied generally as a count distinct window function?

Answer (score 2):

```
create table #MyTable (
Col_A varchar(5),
Col_B int
)

insert into #MyTable values ('A',1)
insert into #MyTable values ('A',1)
insert into #MyTable values ('A',2)
insert into #MyTable values ('A',2)
insert into #MyTable values ('A',2)
insert into #MyTable values ('A',3)

insert into #MyTable values ('B',4)
insert into #MyTable values ('B',4)
insert into #MyTable values ('B',5)


;with t1 as (

select t.Col_A,
       count(*) cnt
 from (
    select Col_A,
           Col_B,
           count(*) as ct
      from #MyTable
     group by Col_A,
              Col_B
  ) t
  group by t.Col_A
 )

select a.*,
       t1.cnt
  from #myTable a
  join t1
    on a.Col_A = t1.Col_a
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative if you're mildly allergic to correlated subqueries (Erik Darling's answer) and CTEs (kevinnwhat's answer) like me.

**Be aware that when nulls are thrown in to the mix, none of these may work how you would like them to.**
(but it's fairly simple to modify them to taste)

Simple case:

```
--ignore the existence of nulls
SELECT [mt].*, [Distinct_B].[Distinct_B]
FROM #MyTable AS [mt]

INNER JOIN(
    SELECT [Col_A], COUNT(DISTINCT [Col_B]) AS [Distinct_B]
    FROM #MyTable
    GROUP BY [Col_A]
) AS [Distinct_B] ON
    [mt].[Col_A] = [Distinct_B].[Col_A]
;
```

Same as above, but with comments on what to change for null handling:

```
--customizable null handling
SELECT [mt].*, [Distinct_B].[Distinct_B]
FROM #MyTable AS [mt]

INNER JOIN(
    SELECT 

    [Col_A],

    (
        COUNT(DISTINCT [Col_B])
        /*
        --uncomment if you also want to count Col_B NULL
        --as a distinct value
        +
        MAX(
            CASE
                WHEN [Col_B] IS NULL
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
        )
        */
    )
    AS [Distinct_B]

    FROM #MyTable
    GROUP BY [Col_A]
) AS [Distinct_B] ON
    [mt].[Col_A] = [Distinct_B].[Col_A]
/*
--uncomment if you also want to include Col_A when it's NULL
OR
([mt].[Col_A] IS NULL AND [Distinct_B].[Col_A] IS NULL)
*/
```